# Sort a NSMutableArray of UIView according to their frame.origin.y

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, nsarray, sorting

I would like to sort an NSMutableArray of UIViews according to their frame.origin.y, I want the lowest view with y to be first etc. It can be the case that 2 UIViews have the same origin. Is there an existing method for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` has several sorting methods. Pick one of them, implement the sorting selector, block or function and compare the `y` values. Here is an example using blocks:

```
NSComparator comparatorBlock = ^(UIView *obj1, UIView *obj2) {
    if (obj1.frame.origin.y > obj2.frame.origin.y) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }

    if (obj1.frame.origin.y < obj2.frame.origin.y) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
};

[array sortUsingComparator:comparatorBlock];
```

Comment: Works like a charme ! thanks man :) didn't know this, and it is so good !

Comment: Thank you! This is really a great help.

Comment: So helpful! Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

While this isn't the frame.origin.y, you can also do this by using a SortDescriptor and looking at the layer.position.y as the key.

```
[array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"layer.position.y" ascending:YES]]];
```

Comment: A much better solution than the answer.. you can sort on the `frame` as it is a struct

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do this in Swift:

```
listOfViews.sortInPlace { CGRectGetMinY($0.frame) < CGRectGetMinY($1.frame) }
```

Thats all :-) All my love to Swift :-)

Answer (score -2):

you can get the array of subviews using

```
yourView.subviews
```

then you can iterate through each and check each frame.origin.y and do your coding